# Одновременное обновления записи в таблице

Tags: c#

Описываю класс (бизнес модель), и необходимо продумать ситуацию когда один объект сохраняют два разных источника.

**Пример:** объект редактируется клиентом, в этот момент его так же редактирует оператор, после сохранения первого второму надо выводить сообщение, что с момента последнего обращения к БД объект был изменен, показать изменения, показать дату изменения и кто вносил изменения, для подтверждения изменений.

Пока придумал для этого использовать свой же класс как поле у текущего, куда хранить объект до начала изменений, и после отправки на сервер - сверять его, пример структуры:

```
class company
{
    private string _name; 
    private string _shortName; 
    private string _postIndex; 
    private company _oldVersion = null;
}
```

Нормальная ли это практика? Или кто-то решает эту проблему по другому?

Comment: На мой взгляд, управлять данными должна заниматься СУБД, а не приложение. (блокировать запись при взятии ее в работу и отпускать когда пользователь закончит с ней работу). Да и тег используемой субд существенно помог бы, DBAшники хоть увидели бы этот вопрос.

Comment: То, что вы хотите - стандартная _оптимистическая блокировка_. Описана практически в любом туториале по работе с СУБД.

Comment: [связанный вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/129329/312041)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я бы не стал гонять `_oldVersion` объект каждый раз.

- Можно вести учет изменениям по дате последнего изменения записи и
  ключа пользователя
- Реализовать потокобезопасную очередь в коде сохранения объекта
- Проверять дату изменения каждый раз при сохранении

В случае отличия даты реализовать логику предупреждения пользователя